# how can I write a program for an __add__ method?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program for an `__add__` method where you have to make each index in 2 lists correspond to each other in order to add them to one another, but I'm a little unsure about how to execute that.

For example, if I had the lists:

```py
a = List([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
b = List([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

and had to add these two objects together like:

```py
c = a + b
```

Then the output would be:

```py
List([3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
```

Here is my code so far:

```py
def __add__(self, rhs: Union[float, Simpy]) -> Simpy:
    result: Simpy = ([])
    if isinstance(rhs, Simpy):
        assert len(self.values) == len(rhs.values)
        for i in rhs.values:
```

For the `for` loop, I want to write something that will make index 0 of the first list correspond with index 0 of the second list, index 1 correspond with index 1, and so on. Thanks for your help!

edit: I forgot to mention that I can't use functions like zip() or map() in this code. I edited my code a bit and this is what I came up with:

```
def __add__(self, rhs: Union[float, Simpy]) -> Simpy:
    result: Simpy = ([])
    if isinstance(rhs, Simpy):
        assert len(self.values) == len(rhs.values)
        for i in range(len(rhs.values)):
            result.values.append(self.values[i] + rhs.values[i])
```

I'm still getting an error though and am not sure what I'm getting wrong. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): `for left, right in zip(leftlist, rightlist)`

Comment: Syntax note: writing `result = ([])` is identical to writing `result = []`. Also, what is `Simpy`?

Comment: Post the error that you're seeing. It's impossible to help with errors unless we know what the error is.

Comment: You seem to be confused about whether `result` is supposed to be a list, or the `Simpy` thing. What is a `Simpy`? Is that your custom `List` class? As-written, `result` is a plain _list_.

Comment: If you can't use map or zip, then it seems like you should just use a for loop for range(len(self)), add the elements at each index and insert them into the result.

Comment: Hi, thank you! You helped me realize that I forgot to make the list one of a Simpy object. Simpy is just a weirdly named class that's supposed to be a heavily inspired/simpler version of NumPy, hence SimPy.  It's for one of my classes in school.

Comment: If you're still getting "an error", we cannot help you unless you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def __add__(self, rhs: Union[float, List]) -> Simpy:
    result: Simpy = ([])
    if isinstance(rhs, Simpy):
        assert len(self.values) == len(rhs.values)
        return [val_1+val_2 for val_1, val_2 in zip(self.values, rhs.values)]
```

Just use a list comprehension to generate a list with the sum of the values. Furthermore, the pythonic way of iterating over multiple iterables is through the use of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: hi, sorry, i forgot to mention a few important things about my code in the post. do you think you could look over the edits I made? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74469449/2954547) suggests using a list comprehension with `zip`. It turns out that the `map` function can also be used this way:

```py
from operator import add

class List:
    def __add__(self, rhs: Union[float, List]) -> List:
        if isinstance(rhs, List):
            return list(map(add, self.values, rhs.values))
```

Python programmers tend to forget that `map` works on more than one iterable! In fact, `zip(*iterables)` is functionally identical to `map(tuple, *iterables)`.

Comment: hey! i forgot to mention a few important things about my code in the post. do you think you could look over the edits I made? Thank you again for your help!